# homebrew: the difference between `prefix.install "some_binary"` and `bin.install "some_binary"`

Tags: ruby, homebrew, recipe

When writing a homebrew recipe,

whats the difference between `prefix.install "some_binary"`
and
`bin.install "some_binary"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the [Formula Cookbook](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Formula-Cookbook.md#variables-for-directory-locations):

```
prefix  #{HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/Cellar/#{name}/#{version}
        /usr/local/Cellar/foo/0.1

bin     #{prefix}/bin
        /usr/local/Cellar/foo/0.1/bin
```

Here, `bin` is the directory where the actual executables are stored, whereas `prefix` contains everything related to a given version of the formula.

You don't want to install a binary in the directory pointed at by `prefix`.